# How many steps would it take to get to the top of this staircase?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

There are 26 steps in a staircase. You have a 51% chance to step onto the next step, and a 49% chance to step back down to the step  prior. Assuming you are already on the first step, how many steps are you most likely to take to before stepping onto the 26th step?

Comment: Assuming you are on the lowest possible step ($0$ or $1$?) what is the distribution of your movement? $51$% forward, $49$% stationary? Or $100$% forward? ...

Comment: 51% forward, and 49% backwards. You never stay stationary from one step to another.

So you would be on the -1th step if you go below 0. It's weird, but you'd still eventually have to make it to the top.

Comment: Ok, got it... so you have infinite steps, and you are beginning at $1$, but terminating at step $26$?

Comment: Yup! That's what I meant. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

A similar version of this question is already answered at [Expected number of steps in a random walk with a boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553690/expected-number-of-steps-in-a-random-walk-with-a-boundary). I understand that here the "coin" is biased but the underlying theory is the same.